# function returning 'a list list instead of 'a list

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, caml-light

The following code is an attempt of creating a function `'a list list -> 'a list` that given a list of lists, gives back a list made of each first element taken from the lists.

```
#let first_element_lists lis =
 let f x y =
    match y with
    [] -> x
    |[]::[] -> x
    |[z]::[zs] -> match [z] with
        [] -> x
        | v::vs -> v::x
in
foldr f [] lis;;


Toplevel input:
>   foldr f [] lis;;
>         ^
This expression has type 'a list -> 'a list list -> 'a list,
but is used with type 'a list -> 'a list list -> 'a list list.
```

I'm really having an hard time trying to figure it out where the error actually is.

Comment: What is `foldr` ? Is it `List.fold_right` ?

Comment: @Bromind you are correct.

Comment: Seems you've switched the arguments of `f` around. `fold_right` uses the opposite order of `fold_left`. Try just swapping `x` and `y`.

Comment: @glennsl I tried what you suggested, but it simply gave the same exact error. This is how `foldr` was defined, https://pastebin.com/ytrWaxVQ

Comment: Your `foldr` is broken. It should be `('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`, not `('a -> 'b list -> 'b list) -> 'c -> 'a list -> 'b list`. (Think about the base case.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks. You're right. I believe the issue is simply in the case where `[ ] -> [ ]`, which should actually be `[ ] -> a`. But does it really matter in this case? Since at `a` is actually passed `[ ]` anyway.

Comment: This is `List.map List.hd`.

Comment: @coredump what/who are you referring to?

Comment: @coredump yep, but List.hd raise a Failure if the list is empty, which doesn't seem to be wanted here.

Comment: @SupremeIndianPooInLoo In `foldr`, you don't know what `a` is - that's part of the point of polymorphism. All you know is that the result should be of the same type as `a`, and the only thing available to you that is of that type is `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
let extract_and_append accumulator element =
match element with
| [] -> accumulator
| hd::_ -> accumulator @ [hd]
```

This function take to lists and it appends the first element of the second one at the end of the first one.

With that, you can use fold_left (hint: always use fold_left if you can, it is tail recursive):

```
let first_element_lists llist = 
List.fold_left extract_and_append [] llist
```

where `llist` is your `list` of `list`.

For instance :

```
first_element_lists [[11; 12; 13]; [21; 22; 23]; [31; 32; 33]];;
- : int list = [11; 21; 31]
```

Hint: when using fold_left, fold_right, map, etc... if you're not confident with the function you provide, create a real named function (i.e. with `let ... in`), so you can verify it has the type you want.

Comment: Wow, really concise and precise. What I don't understand is, if `llist` is a `a list list` how can then `element` become a `a list` instead of remaining `a list list` as previously declared?

Comment: Fold_left take the first element of `llist`, i.e. a `'a list`, then it takes the second one, etc.. An element of, say, an `'a list` is an `'a`, hence if `llist` is `'b list list`, then `'a` is `'b list`, thus `element` is indeed a `'b list` (well, renamed to `'a list`).

Comment: when you say `hint: always use fold_left if you can, it is tail recursive` you mean I should use `fold_left` when I want to scroll a list from `left-to-right`?

Comment: What I meant is that, most of the time, you can do what you want using either `fold_left` or `fold_right`. Indeed, they don't scroll the list the same direction, and a few modification might be required (for instance, you can see that in `extract_and_append` above, I append the head at the end of the accumulator while using `fold_right`, one would have appened it at the begining), but for most operations, it is feasible easily. The thing is that both `fold_*` are almost the same, but "almost" is sufficient to allow a zero-cost recursion (i.e. a `jump` instead of a `call`).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, which relies entirely on the standard library :

```
let firsts l = List.map List.hd l
```

See it in action :

```
firsts [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]];;
- : int list = [1; 4; 7]
```

- `List.map` applies a function to every element of a list and returns of list with all the results.
- `List.hd` is a function that returns the first element (called the *head*) of a list.

---

As mentioned in the comments, this fails when one of the lists is empty.

```
firsts [[1;2;3]; []];;

Exception: (Failure hd).
Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 32, characters 22-33
Called from file "list.ml", line 67, characters 20-23
Called from file "list.ml", line 67, characters 32-39
Called from file "toplevel/toploop.ml", line 180, characters 17-56
```

You can work around this in a variety of ways, one of which is [Bromind's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184951/3092183).

Comment: Yep, this was mentionned in the comments also, but as I said there, it raises a Failure if one sublist is empty, which didn't seem to be wanted by OP.

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see it in the comment. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I like this proposal, for the empty list case we can perhaps filter it : l |> List.filter (fun x -> x != []) |> List.map List.hd

Comment: Core makes `List.hd` return `'a option`, which can be used to do something similar. :)